# XML Validate. Get error numbers

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xsd

How can i catch error code when validate XML document with XSD schema?

Answer (score 2):

You can catch it in delegate `ValidationEventHandler` which you pass to `Validate` method.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340331(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. But I need to get number of error. I don't need error message.

Comment: Every error message must have error number. For example "The element 'SLUCH' has invalid child element 'RSLT'. List of possible elements expected: 'DS1'." must have number 1 and "The 'EXTR' element is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://volgatfoms.ru:int2' - The string '' is not a valid Integer value." must have 2  etc.